# Styles applied on wrong breakpoints in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, safari, breakpoints

I have the breakpoints set at 1024 and 768, for example. In chrome and firefox, the styles apply correctly at the specific breaking points, so the styles change at 1023 and 767.
In safari however, instead of changing at 1023px and 767px, the styles change at 1038 and 783. The same happens on all user agents on safari (ie, chrome, firefox, for both mac and windows)

Why would this happen?
I am using nuxt and tailwind.

Comment: Would be helpful to provide a code sample

Comment: of how i wrote the break points?